# Replace MacPorts dependency with other package

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports

Is there a way to satisfy a certain port dependency with another package (than the specified one) in MacPorts? More specifically, to use the package XYZ-devel instead of just XYZ for a second port that requires XYZ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `-devel` port is not offered as a variant, then the only way is to edit the Portfile.

```
$ sudo port edit $the_port
```

will open the specified port in an editor. You can change the dependency from the release port to the `-devel` port there.

Note that:

1. This may break the port, since it may not work with the `-devel` version (unlikely, but possible).
2. Your changes to the Portfile will get reverted anytime you do a `port selfupdate`. If you don't want to have to "fix" the Portfile each time you update, you may want to set up a [local Portfile repository](http://guide.macports.org/#development.local-repositories).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What I do now is copying the X-devel port to my local repository, and renaming it to X. Additionally, I download the patches to that directory so that it finds them (otherwise it would attempt to download them from the directory of the X-devel port on the server).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "port variants" command to display the list of available variants for a given port. Ex:

```
[michaelsafyan@codemage ~]$ port variants ffmpeg
ffmpeg has the variants:
   darwin_10: Platform variant, selected automatically
   no_gpl: disallow use of GPL code, license will be LGPL
   no_mmx: disable all x86 asm optimizations
   speex: enable Speex decoding via libspeex
```

You can then use "+*variantname*" to activate or "-*variantname*" to deactivate a given variant for the install (for example, one can use "sudo port install ffmpeg +speex" to install ffmpeg with the speex variant). This is the only way (that won't break MacPorts) that you can select between different configurations and dependencies.